# I would like to display only one post at fronted (dajngo framework)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have posted several posts but am unable to display only one post at the front end from several posts. instead, it displays all the post which is not correct. help appreciated, thank you

**views.py**

```
def ann(request):
    ann = Announcement.objects.all()
    context = {
        'ann': ann
    }
    return render(request, 'Announcement.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Community</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap@5.1.3.css' %}">

    <!-- Style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}
 {% for ann in ann %}
 {% if forloop.first %}
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 col-sm-10" style="margin: auto;">
      <div class="row">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title" style="text-align: right; border-bottom: 2px solid; color:  #46a271; padding: 17px; overflow: hidden;
              top: 0;
              z-index: -1000;
              
              ">
              <p style="color: #0e3d42;">Category: {{ann.name}}</p>  </h4>
              <br>
              <p class="card-text" style="text-align: center;">{{ann.body|safe}}</p>
              <p> Post created on {{ann.created_date}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
{% include 'footer.html' %}
    {% endblock %}


  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Custom Script -->
  <!-- <script>
      function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
          var element = document.querySelector(selector);
              let truncated = element.innerText;

          if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
              truncated = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
          }

          console.log(truncated)
          return truncated;
      }

      document.querySelector('.body-text').innerText = truncateText('.body-text', 140);
  </script> -->
  <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Note: Unable to display only one page in announcement.html file as mentioned above and also used filter, I need to display all posts when I click to read more button

Answer (score 0):

Your view is using a queryset which returns all of your announcement objects and then your template loops over all of those announcements. I can see that you are attempting to use an 'if' statement in your template which catches only a single iteration of this loop, but generally speaking, having this type of logic in the template layer could be considered bad practice.

Depending on which announcement you wish to return, first of all you will need to modify this part of your view:

```
ann = Announcement.objects.all()
```

You can [limit a queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) in various different ways, for example:

```
Announcement.objects.order_by('some_date_column')[0]
```

...would get the oldest Announcement, however I'm guessing that you probably want to dynamically return a different single announcement based on something like a primary key or slug.

Add a [url route](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) along the lines of this, ('pk' being primary key of the announcement which you wish to retrieve):

```
urlpatterns = [

path("annoucements/<int:pk>/", ann, name="annoucement_detail"),

 ]
```

```
def ann(request, pk):
    ann = Announcement.objects.filter(id=pk)
    context = {
        'ann': ann
    }
    return render(request, 'Announcement.html', context)
```

or even better

```
def announcement_detail(request, pk):
     annoucement = get_object_or_404(Announcement, id=pk)
     context = {
        'annoucement': annoucement 
        }
    return render(request, 'Announcement.html', context)
```

Then you can simply remove the loop logic in your template. You are now passing a single object into your context, rather than retrieving all the Announcement objects from your DB and filtering them out in the template.

Another approach would be to utilize Django's  Generic Class Based Views. The [Detail View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) solves this problem.